# Property object doesn't keep class prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to set prototype of an object using
`Object.setPrototypeOf(data,RouteModel.prototype)`

at the purpose of use an existing class with methods.

The defined class is the following:

```js
export class RouteModel {
    constructor(public absoluteurl:string,public routes:RouteItemModel[]){}
    public gettext()
    {
        return 'asdassdasd'
    }
}
```

and it contains a property `routes` as array of `RouteItemModel` that contains a method:

```js
export class RouteItemModel {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public source_type: string,
    public method: string,
    public path: string
  ) {}

  public getColorByMethod(): string {
    switch (this.method.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'get':
        return 'success';
      case 'put':
        return 'warning';
      case 'delete':
        return 'danger';
        default:
            return "primary"
    }
  }
}
```

On the object.assign the main object go ok and I can use the `gettext()` method, but the `routes` property doesn't change so I can't use the `getColorByMethod()` method.

What's wrong?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (including the `Object.assign` call and whatever makes you think *"...the `routes` property doesn't change"*), something we can copy and paste directly into our own IDEs to see the problem.

Comment: Beware that `Object.assign` does a shallow copy, so if you do `const a = Object.assign({}, b);`, `a.routes` and `b.routes` will refer to the **same** array.

Comment: (Having said that, using `setPrototypeOf` should be a ***last*** resort solution when nothing else will work. With the above, why not just create an instance of `RouteModel` in the usual way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend **not** using `setPrototypeOf` if you have ***any*** other option, and you almost always do. Instead, just create a `RouteModel` and its `RouteItemModel`s directly:

```
const result = new RouteModel(
    data.absolute_url,
    data.routes.map(({name, source_type, method, path}) => new RouteItemModel(
        name,
        source_type,
        method,
        path,
    ))
)
```

It would probably be worthwhile to add a `from` method to `RouteModel` and `RouteItemModel` to encapsulate those operations.

---

If you did have to set `setPrototypeOf`...

> ...but the routes property doesn't change so I can't use the `getColorByMethod()` method.

Just setting the prototype of `data` has no effect on those route objects, you'd also have to set the prototype of each route, something like this:

```
// REALLY DON'T RECOMMEND THIS
Object.setPrototypeOf(data, RouteModel.prototype);
for (const route of data.routes) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(route, RouteItemModel.prototype);
}
```

Again, though, resetting the prototype of existing objects is (almost?) never necessary and its confusing to people reading the code. (It used to impact the subsequent performance of those objects as well, although that rarely mattered; I haven't checked lately to see if that's still true, since I never do this.)

Comment: Ok, in this case it seems work properly, but what happens if I would have a recursive object or simply an object with lots of properties?

Comment: @calabreseluca - You can discover the properties at runtime if it's really necessary, but that's part of what I meant about a `from` operation on the classes, so the list of properties is in a single place (the class). But to do it dynamically, see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).